# Azure devops VSTS not installing awscli now on my host, used to work

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, aws-cli

Somehow this isn't working anymore, Installing with CMD, I tried with many different hosts, but usually do VS HOSTED 2017. It was working the other day and past few weeks. Any suggestions

pip install awscli

```
Generating script.
Script contents:
pip install awscli
##[command]"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL 
"D:\a\_temp\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.cmd""
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: Add AWS CLI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you now have to use 'Use Python Version' step
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/470321/cmd-pip-install-awscli-doesnt-work-anymore.html